# Get property names as strings from a input string

Tags: c#

I am currently creating a module which will create merge fields in word using Gembox.Document from C#. First of all, I just want to say that this is a task that I have been given, so wether this is a bad way to do it or not, this is the way they want it.

I have a Windows forms application where there is a textbox and a button. In the textbox, they want the possibility to paste a dto/model, for example:

```
"public class Example 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Cellphone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }  
}"
```

I already have the logic to add mergefields to word with a method where I pass in a string[] which contains all the merge field names.

PROBLEM IS: I need to be able to somehow substring this big string above which contains a dto/model written as a string in the textbox, to get the property names and add them to the `string[]`, since they will be the merge field names.

I hope I could explain myself well enough. This is my first question here and I am not used to explain my problems in English.

EDIT:
**To specify the problem: I need to get the property names out of this string and put them into an `string[]`:**

```
string s = @"public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set; }
  public string Cellphone { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }
  public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }"
```

Comment: Are you trying to parse a type from a string?

Comment: I guess you could parse that with Roslyn. Or if you're sure the format will always be as simple as this, use a regex like `\w+(?=\s*\{\s*get\b)`

Comment: If I am correct, you are expecting your application to perform like how a compiler identify. So it's better you read about something related to it.

Comment: I am not sure that I explained myself well enough, please check my edit

Comment: \w+(?=\s*\{\s*get\b) this regex only gives me the first property name

Comment: @Jokerish use `.Matches` instead of `.Match` - the regex works fine ([see here](https://regex101.com/r/iE3cC8/1)) but it's a hacky solution to your problem.

Comment: Why is it hacky? Sorry, but as you may have figured, I'm not really a pro programmer, I'm a student and I'm kind of new to these things

Comment: It's hacky because it's not a rigorous solution. For instance, this will pick up properties which were commented out. If you want a rigorous solution, use a C# parser ([Roslyn](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) has one).

Comment: Ok, thank you really much mate. If you have time and want to, I would appreciate an example of how to do this for it to work in my case. If not, thanks anyway, you have been helpful!

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what you need. If it's a list of property names as an array of strings, then the expected output should be different, similar to that of the Fabjan's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that maybe you should parse this text (using parser not own solution) and than search syntax tree to find properties names. I think about something similar to this:

[Using NRefactory for analyzing C# code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/408663/Using-NRefactory-for-analyzing-Csharp-code)

This code returns complete tree or error (I use NRefactory but you can use Roslyn):

```
var parser = new CSharpParser();
var syntaxTree = parser.Parse(programCode);
```

than search *syntaxTree* field for properties.

Example code:

```
const string code = @"public class Example {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Cellphone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }
}";
var syntaxTree = new CSharpParser().Parse(code, "program.cs");
var listOfPropertiesNames = syntaxTree.Children
    .SelectMany(astParentNode => astParentNode.Children)
    .OfType<PropertyDeclaration>()
    .Select(astPropertyNode => astPropertyNode.Name)
    .ToList();
```

This snippet extract properties names.

Comment: I am not sure that I explained myself well enough, please check my edit

Comment: @Jokerish this answers your question, and using a C# parser in the best approach IMO.

Comment: Can you give a more exact example of how I shall use this method to achieve what I want? I'm pretty new to these stuff

Comment: This answer, together with the regex "\w+(?=\s*\{\s*get\b)" solved my problem. Thank you, mate. Really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSharpCodeProvider class to compile your code to an assembly, and then use reflection to find the types in the compiled assembly.

```
var sourcePart = @"public class Example 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Cellphone { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }
}";

    var sourceTemplate = @"using System;

    @code

";

var code = sourceTemplate.Replace("@code", sourcePart);

CSharpCodeProvider c = new CSharpCodeProvider();

CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

CompilerResults cr = c.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, code);
if (cr.Errors.Count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + cr.Errors[0].ErrorText,
        "Error evaluating cs code", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
           MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}

var a = cr.CompiledAssembly;

var type = a.GetTypes().Single();

string[] propertyNames = type.GetProperties().Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
```

UPDATE:
Remeber however, that a type loaded in an app domain can't be unloaded, and will keep consuming memory until the application exit.

So if the user works with this function a lot, memory would be consumed incrementally.

If this becomes a problem, you can workaround this by creating a separate app domain or spawn another process to serve this function, but it's another question.

Comment: I am not sure that I explained myself well enough, please check my edit

Comment: updated the answer, now you've got your properties in a string[]

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom static method to parse your text. What it does it jumps across string from one index of '{' to next index goes backward and checks if there is '(' or ')' char (which indicates that it is a method and not a property and it should skip it) and goes backwards to find the beginning of the property. After that it extracts value, then jumps to next index of '{' char and so on  :

```
    static string[] GetProperties(string dirty)
    {
        List<string> properties = new List<string>();
        int i = dirty.IndexOf("{ ");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int propEndIndex = -1; int i2 = -1;

        for (; i != -1; i = dirty.IndexOf("{ ", i + 1))
        {
            i2 = i - 1;

            for (; dirty[i2] == ' '; i2--) { }

            if (dirty[i2] == '(' || dirty[i2] == ')') continue;

            propEndIndex = i2 + 1;

            for (; dirty[i2] != ' '; i2--) { }                

            for (i2++; i2 < propEndIndex; i2++)
                sb.Append(dirty[i2]);                

            properties.Add(sb.ToString());
            sb.Clear();
        }

        return properties.ToArray();
    }
```

Example of usage :

```
       Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        var s = @"public class Example 
                {
                   public string Name { get; set; }
                   public string Surname { get; set; }
                   public string Cellphone { get; set; }
                   public string Address { get; set; }
                   public string CompanyName { get; set; }
                   public DateTime CurrentDate { get; set; }  

                   public void MyMethod() { }
                }";

        sw.Start();

        string[] props =  GetProperties(s);

        sw.Stop();

        foreach (var item in props)
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        Console.WriteLine("\n\nMethod is executed in " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
Name
Surname 
CellPhone
Address
CompanyName 
CurrentDate

Method is executed in 1 ms
```

Comment: @Bauss Regardless of how it looks it performs better than LINQ. It uses simple `for` loop and is something around `O(n)`

Comment: Yeah I did not say it performed bad, I'm just speaking in regards on the `look`

Comment: Thank you very much for contributing to solve my problem. I've alredady found I way to solve it though, with help from above answers. But I think that this method would also solve my problems, and I hope that someday it helps someone else solve their problem.